# Combine Time-series with time-invariant data in RNN/LSTM using Keras Functional API

Tags: tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

*Update: As [rvinas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5140223/rvinas) pointed out, I had forgotten to add inputs_aux as second `input` in `Model`. Fixed now, and it works. So ConditionalRNN can readily be used to do what I want.*

I'd like to treat time-series together with non-time-series characteristics in extended LSTM cells (a requirement also discussed [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/17099)). [ConditionalRNN (cond-rnn)](https://github.com/philipperemy/cond_rnn) for Tensorflow in Python seems to allow this.

Can it be used in Keras Functional API (without eager execution)?
That is, does anyone have a clue how to fix my failed approach below, or a different example where ConditionalRNN (or alternatives) are used to readily combine TS and non-TS data in LSTM-style cells or any equivalent?

I've seen the eager execution-bare tf example on [Pilippe Remy's ConditionalRNN github page](https://github.com/philipperemy/cond_rnn), but I did not manage to extend it to a readily fittable version in Keras Functional API.

My code looks as follows; it works if, instead of the ConditionalRNN, I use a standard LSTM cell (and adjust the model 'x' input correspondingly). With ConditionalRNN, I did not get it to execute; I receive either the `must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'in_aux'` error (cf. below), or instead some different type of input size complaints when I change the code, despite trying to be careful about data dimensions compatibility.

(Using Python 3.6, Tensorflow 2.1, cond-rnn 2.1, on Ubuntu 16.04)

```
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Input
from cond_rnn import ConditionalRNN

inputs = Input(name='in',shape=(5,5)) # Each observation has 5 dimensions à 5 time-steps each
x = Dense(64)(inputs)

inputs_aux = Input(name='in_aux', shape=[5]) # For each of the 5 dimensions, a non-time-series observation too
x = ConditionalRNN(7, cell='LSTM')([x,inputs_aux]) # Updated Syntax for cond_rnn v2.1
# x = ConditionalRNN(7, cell='LSTM', cond=inputs_aux)(x) # Syntax for cond_rnn in some version before v2.1

predictions = Dense(1)(x)
model = Model(inputs=[inputs, inputs_aux], outputs=predictions) # With this fix, [inputs, inputs_aux], it now works, solving the issue
#model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mse'])
data = np.random.standard_normal([100,5,5]) # Sample of 100 observations with 5 dimensions à 5 time-steps each
data_aux = np.random.standard_normal([100,5]) # Sample of 100 observations with 5 dimensions à only 1 non-time-series value each
labels = np.random.standard_normal(size=[100]) # For each of the 100 obs., a corresponding (single) outcome variable

model.fit([data,data_aux], labels)
```

The error I get is

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'in_aux' with dtype float and shape [?,5]
     [[{{node in_aux}}]]
```

and the traceback is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/florian/temp_nonclear/playground/test/est1ls_bare.py", line 20, in <module>
    model.fit({'in': data, 'in_aux': data_aux}, labels) #model.fit([data,data_aux], labels) # Also crashes when using model.fit({'in': data, 'in_aux': data_aux}, labels)
  File "/home/florian/BB/tsgenerator/ts_wgan/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 643, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "/home/florian/BB/tsgenerator/ts_wgan/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 664, in fit
    steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
  File "/home/florian/BB/tsgenerator/ts_wgan/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 383, in model_iteration
    batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "/home/florian/BB/tsgenerator/ts_wgan/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 3353, in __call__
    run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
  File "/home/florian/BB/tsgenerator/ts_wgan/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1458, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the definition of your model be `model = Model(inputs=[inputs, inputs_aux], outputs=predictions)`?

Comment: Thanks @rvinas, you solved my problem (if you post an answer I could accept it, even if my mistake was so bad)

Comment: @FlorianH I tried to run the corrected code but got an error TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'cond'). Do you know the reason for this mismatch.

Comment: @Malintha The latests cond-rnn, v 2.1, seems to require `x = ConditionalRNN(7, cell='LSTM')([x,inputs_aux])` instead of `x = ConditionalRNN(7, cell='LSTM', cond=inputs_aux)(x)`. Makes it work again for me. Cf. __call__ definition in cond_rnn/cond_rnn.py

Comment: @FlorianH yes, it is working fine with that input mode. Thanks

Comment: @FlorianH, I have another question related to your posted code. This is not related to the issue but I am trying to understand the use case. You have mentioned 'each dimension has non-time-variant observation'. I am trying to understand it. Let's say we have 3 time variant features we observe overtime, and 4 t-invariant features. So, at each time step, our input size to cell is 3. Now we are going to initialize the cell. In this case we have 4 t-inv features which should be used to create conditions on each time-var input. So is it correct to use MLP to learn each condition. Please explain.

Comment: @Malintha, sorry I cannot answer it spontaneously.

Comment: @FlorianH, it is fine. I  will try to do it.

Comment: @FlorianH The given explanations for different dimensions of data and data_aux tensors are not clear to me. How many time series do you have in total? do time series have the same number of time steps? How many time varying and constant variables do you have, correspondingly?Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that you are not passing `inputs_aux` as input to your model. TF is complaining because this tensor is required to compute your output `predictions` and it is not being fed with any value. Defining your model as follows should solve the problem:

```
model = Model(inputs=[inputs, inputs_aux], outputs=predictions)
```